# Auto-SSH works manually but not in background

Tags: ssh, cron, background-process, autossh

I'm running the following script on `@reboot` cron with `root`:

```
autossh -f -i /home/pi/.ssh/myRemote.pem -R 2210:localhost:22 ubuntu@server.com
```

When I run manually it works fine but from `cron` I see it show in the logs continually failing:

```
Nov 25 01:15:56 kirkins autossh[1936]: starting ssh (count 1)
Nov 25 01:15:56 kirkins autossh[1936]: ssh child pid is 1947
Nov 25 01:16:01 kirkins autossh[1936]: ssh exited prematurely with status 130; autossh exiting
Nov 25 01:16:40 kirkins autossh[605]: starting ssh (count 13)
Nov 25 01:16:40 kirkins autossh[605]: ssh child pid is 1949
Nov 25 01:16:40 kirkins autossh[605]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
Nov 25 01:18:48 kirkins autossh[605]: starting ssh (count 14)
Nov 25 01:18:48 kirkins autossh[605]: ssh child pid is 1970
Nov 25 01:18:49 kirkins autossh[605]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
```

Anyone know what's going wrong? I saw some related posts on other StackExchange sites but none of the solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is probably that `ssh` does not like the fact that it is started without a controlling terminal (`cron` children do not have one).

You could try `ssh -tt`. Or run it within `screen` / `tmux`.

Comment: For `tmux` would I just do `tmux ssh ...`?

Comment: no luck with `autossh -tt`

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I am not familiar with `tmux` and thus do not know the syntax. The man page knows the answer.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Maybe it works if you execute a command via `ssh` which never (or after a long time) exists like `sleep 100000`.

Comment: I'm finding the combination of `-tt` with `sleep infinity` solves my issue, thanks.